# Select all Groups and check if User is in a Group or not

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables `groups` and `groups_members`

#### groups

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | GROUP 1 |
| 2 | GROUP 2 |
| 3 | GROUP 2 |

#### groups_members

| group_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | 555 |
| 1 | 4643 |
| 3 | 45434 |

Now I want to display ALL groups and check if the user i show the groups for (lets say `user_id = 555`) is in a group or not. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT g.id, g.name, is_in_group 
FROM g.groups 
JOIN groups_members gm ON gm.user_id = 555
```

Expected output:

| id | name | is_in_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GROUP 1 | NULL |
| 2 | GROUP 2 | 1 |
| 3 | GROUP 3 | NULL |

Comment: ```SELECT group, EXISTS (SELECT member ..) ..```

Comment: how would the complete EXISTS subquery look like?

Comment: [Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) - the subquery looks like ones in example queries in the article.

Comment: or for fun/variety `SELECT g.id, g.name, LEAST(gm.id,1) AS is_in_group FROM g.groups LEFT JOIN groups_members gm ON g.id = gm.id AND gm.user_id = 555`

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do so, a simple trick that comes to my mind is this one:

```sql
SELECT 
  g.*, 
  CAST(gm.user_id / gm.user_id AS UNSIGNED) AS is_in_group
FROM sgroups AS g
LEFT JOIN sgroups_members AS gm 
  ON g.id = gm.group_id 
  AND gm.user_id = 555;

-- id   name        is_in_group
-- 1    GROUP 1     NULL
-- 2    GROUP 2     1
-- 3    GROUP 3     NULL
```